# Creating a simple youtube video player using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube

I'm trying to create a simple youtube player using some javascript. Example is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YX8pQ/6/

I've got the basic functionality working (kinda) using click functions to toggle the visibility of each iframe.

HOWEVER:

> 1. When clicking each thumbnail in succession, loading the iframes becomes a bit buggy; sometimes the video you click doesn't load, and sometimes (no idea why!) a different video loads.
> 2. When clicking a different thumbnail, currently-playing videos keep on loading.

Is there a more elegant/robust way of doing this? It's a pretty simple function but I can't seem to work out a better way to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide the previous video frame before toggling the new one. See updated example : http://jsfiddle.net/ampersand/YX8pQ/8/

I've created a vidframe class on each iframe. This is used in the css as well as in the jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to solve the problems you have with your video player, but in case you rethink it, you could use [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/), it's awesome, and has streaming also :)